# Turn pre-paired USB bluetooth dongle into generic bluetooth adapter

Tags: usb, drivers, mouse, bluetooth, adapter

I want to have bluetooth capabilities on my PC, but I don't have a bluetooth adapter.

I do however, have a bunch of USB bluetooth dongles from wireless mice and keyboards, I understand that these are pre-paired with the corresponding devices and only need to be connected to the USB port.

Is there anyway that I can turn these dongles into generic bluetooth adapters? In the sense that I can discover devices and pair with any device?

When I connect one of these dongles to my PC it will detect the dongle as a "USB Receiver" and then when the dongle finds the mice/keyboard, a regular device will also be detected (mouse or keyboard).

Perhaps if I uninstalled the USB Receiver driver and tried to use a generic bluetooth driver it'd work?

I'm not sure if what I am asking is possible.

Comment: If the USB dongles don't have a Bluetooth logo on them, then they aren't Bluetooth.  Many wireless mouse and keyboards use proprietary radio standards and aren't Bluetooth.

Comment: Yeah I believe you're right, I don't have bluetooth dongles at all. The funny thing is it actually says "bluetooth wireless" on one of the boxes, I guess that's what cheap mice gets you. I guess the solution is to buy a bluetooth adapter.